# Keeping all data in a dataframe with exceptions for particular rows in 2 columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I need to keep everything except when the `ETA` is '5 business days' and '8 business days' for 2 `Booking Date` only '30th October' and '31st October'. I am pretty sure this will involve the grep function but I don't know how to do it with such conditions.

My original dataset has 14 columns with many more variables but here is a sample....

```css
DF
Booking Date        ETA                 Address
8th October         4 business days     1 Lane Drive
30th October        5 business days     2 Daisy Rd
31st October        1 business day      5 Bay St
31st October        8 business days     10 Charlotte St
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(!(Booking_Date %in% c('30th October','31st October') & 
             ETA %in% c('5 business days','8 business days')))
```

Output is:

```
  Booking_Date             ETA      Address
1  8th October 4 business days 1 Lane Drive
2 31st October  1 business day     5 Bay St
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(Booking_Date = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("30th October", 
"31st October", "8th October"), class = "factor"), ETA = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("1 business day", "4 business days", 
"5 business days", "8 business days"), class = "factor"), Address = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("1 Lane Drive", "10 Charlotte St", "2 Daisy Rd", 
"5 Bay St"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Booking_Date", "ETA", 
"Address"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```